# Is there a way a c# attribute can be sent a parameter from the method it is used on

Tags: c#, attributes

How can I pass into an attribute a parameter that was sent to the function that this attribute was used on?  e.g. I need to do something like this...

```cs
[Authorize, AuthorizeLimited( ModuleID=pageModuleId)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MoveModule(int pageModuleId, int sequence)
{
    db.PageModule_Move(pageModuleId, sequence);
    return Json("OK");
}
```

The pageModuleId sent to the method must also go to the attribute.  Sorry if this has already been asked I couldn't find an answer.

EDIT

OK using the answer provided by @jrummell here is my first action filter attribute :)  This is simply to stop someone editing a module (used by ajax) who does not have the perms.

```
public class AuthorizeModuleEditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private int _moduleID;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in filterContext.ActionParameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Key == "pageModuleId")
            {
                _moduleID = (int)filterContext.ActionParameters["pageModuleId"];
            }
        }

        if (!SiteHelper.UserPermsForModule(_moduleID)) //checks if user has perms to edit module
            throw (new Exception("Invalid user rights"));

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, attribute parameter values must be compile time constants.

However, if you [implement your own action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx), you can override `OnActionExecuting` and inspect the action parameters in [`filterContext.ActionParamters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.actionparameters.aspx).

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    foreach(var parameter in filterContext.ActionParameters)
    {
        if (parameter.Key == "pageModuleId")
        {
             // do something with pageModuleId
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is associated with the method - not to a method call and its parameters.